# PHP Concatenation into a textarea and using new lines?

Tags: php, concatenation

How do I make the id=Conversation Text area concatenate the string of  $Convo so that it will continue the response by either the user or by RoboAI to be 2 newlines underneath not the last response?

Currently it does it correctly after the first response by user but then the all the responses after that just push the previously reply back to the line with top line until it can't anymore and then goes to the second line and continue with that pattern.

Comment: Without some code, your question is unanswerable.

Comment: Concatenation is done in PHP using the dot `.` operation. Is that what you're asking? Newlines are generated using `\n`... so if I understand correctly: `$newString = $oldString . '\n\n' . $response;` and then `<textarea ...><?=$newString; ?></textarea>`?

Comment: `\n` in single quotes isn't a new line @AlejandroIván https://eval.in/761569

Comment: @chris85 you're right, those should double quotes (`"`).